# sum the numbers of a column of "x" previous rows

Tags: bash, awk

I have a script with a loop of 5 iterations. In each iteration, the script add lines to an output file. The output file looks like this in the second iteration:

```
#First
Total: 10
Sub: 3
Del: 4
Total2:13
#----------#
#Second:
Total: 15
Sub: 7
Del: 8
Total2:25
#----------#
```

What I want: A line between Del and Total2, with the sum of Total + Sub + Del. So, what I have tried is to put this command (see below) after the "Del" line is printed out, and before "Total2" is printed out.

```
awk '!/^#/ {s+=$2} END {print s}' file
```

It works only for the first iteration.
My desired output:

```
#First
Total: 10
Sub: 3
Del: 4
Sum: 17
Total2:13
#----------#
#Second:
Total: 15
Sub: 7
Del: 8
Sum: 30
Total2:25
#----------#
```

So, I want to find a way to sum only the values of the second column of the previos 3 lines.

I hope I'm explaining...
An awk or bash solution could be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but your `awk` program doesn't print out the rest of the file.  Here's a quick example I whipped up:

```
$ cat script
/^#/ { s = 0 }                # reset s on lines starting with #
!/^#/ { s += $2 }             # add to s on lines that *don't* start with #
/^Total2/ { print "Sum:", s } # print out sum before printing Total2
{ print $0 }                  # print current line
```

Running it on your input file:

```
$ awk -f script file 
#First
Total: 10
Sub: 3
Del: 4
Sum: 17
Total2:13
#----------#
#Second:
Total: 15
Sub: 7
Del: 8
Sum: 30
Total2:25
#----------#
```

Comment: Ok this work properly if I run it after I have the entire output file created. My solution is you want to add the sum at the same time that the output being created... I understand myself xD. Thanks!

Comment: Oh I see - I think I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I feel I bit stupid. Just adding bash "`tail`" command before the awk, the problem is solved:

```
tail -3 prova.txt | awk '!/^#/ {s+=$2} END {print "Sum: "s}'
```

Comment: I don't see show that can generate the output you're looking for.  That `awk` program just outputs a single number.

Comment: Maybe I have explained myself incorrectly. The first table is generated in a script that I have already writen. But I wanted to add another line with the sum... :S. Sorry if I explained the question ambiguously.